Google Tag Manager - Trigger off Custom JS Variable
I have a trigger that does work which is a custom event > some custom events. {{dlv - email}} contains @
{{dlv - email}} pulls information from the following code
`<script>
(function () {
  var element = document.querySelector('input[name="contact_details_email"]') 

  element.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  dataLayer.push({
                    'event': 'email', 
                    'email': e.target.value                   
              });
  }, true);
})();  
</script>`

I have another variable {{JS contact form country}} which is custom JavaScript as it's pulling data from a drop down selection.
`function () {
    var country = document.getElementById('country_id').selectedOptions[0].text;
    if (country)
        return country;
    else 
        return "Country not selected";  
}
`

I'm trying to use the above in a trigger which is a custom event > some custom events. {{JS contact form country}} contains Australia
However it's not working as the first example.
Can anyone explain what the difference is and offer any guidance?

And educated guess would be that your custom variable is evaluated only once and then retains its value later on.  You can check this in the preview if you test if the variable actually changes its value at some event.
In contrast, the first example is a function that will be run every time that tag is triggered and thus generate new values.
You might have to implement an event listener for that dropdown in a custom HTML tag instead, and push the value to the datalayer
